# Why does the R pager hide git output?

Tags: r

R comes with a "pager" in bin. When R is in my PATH this prevents some programs (especially git, but also man) to display the output correctly.

I get correct behavior by "export PAGER=less" .

But why is it there at all and not playing nice with unix (i.e. a bug) or is this specific to my setup?

e.g.: man echo

> ```
> /X/Y/Z/R-3.2.1/bin/pager: line 9: -s: No such file or directory
> man: command exited with status 1: LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page echo(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page echo(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$ MAN_PN=echo(1) pager -s
> ```